# How to Intercept non public members with castle dynamic proxy?

Tags: castle-windsor, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

Is it possible to intercept non-public methods with Castle Dynamic Proxy?

Will something like this work to intercept non-public members?

```
 base.BootStrapContainer.Register(
                    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(referencedAssembly)
                           .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                           .Pick()
                           .Configure(component => component.Interceptors<TracingAspect>()));
```

Comment: Take a step back and look at the design of your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: As far I know, members can't be intercepted unless virtual, interface members are virtual by default. I am asking the question in first place for confirmation of that, but your comment is really quite not helpful, because you assumed I designed the application.

Comment: I do agree with your answer here though about design, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net/14062850#14062850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only members that are public to dynamic proxy can be intercepted.