# Adding a Key Check to all attempts to access any functions in a WebService

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, api, asmx

I am building a Web Service API to provide remote access data from a management system.

There are various functions in the API and all require an access key.

I am currently wrapping the insides of all functions like this:

```
Function GETSOMETHING(api_key)
    If IntegratedApis.Grant_Api_Access(api_key) Then
        /// DO STUFF
    Else
        Return "API KEY not provided or incorrect"
    End
 End Function
```

Obviously my `IntegratedApis.Grant_Api_Access(api_key)` function returns a boolean output and checks the user's `key` in the database

This works, but the problem is it's a bit of a maintenance pain. How can I automatically wrap this around ALL calls to the webservice?

Is it possible via the `global.asax` file to return the error on `Application_BeginRequest` for example?

Comment: Are you using Web API for building web services?

Comment: No, I am using Visual Web Developer 2010

Comment: @JamieHartnoll: not the tool. what technology are you using? http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to all this. I am using an ASMX webservice, coding in VB. I'll read up some more...

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) frameworks for .NET. These frameworks basically intercept all calls and run them through a function that relies heavily on reflection.

For example:

```
// Original function call that you want routed through AOP.
[KeyCheck]
public void OriginalFunctionCall() {
     ...
}

// AOP function that accepts all functions that were decorated with [KeyCheck].
// Runs logic before the function, runs the function, runs logic after.
public void Intercept() {
    // Before original function.
    keyCheck();

    // Original function
    functionCall();

    // Logic after original function.
    cleanUp();
}
```

Some of the frameworks let you put an annotation on all calls you want routed through the AOP framework. When I've used this approach, you have any logic you want performed *before* your call executed, then the call is executed, then any logic you want performed *after* the original call.

Some .NET AOP frameworks:

- http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net
- http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx
- Long list from SO:
  [What is the best implementation for AOP in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net)

Last note: Be careful with performance. Some of the frameworks - since they use reflection heavily - can slow down your code.