# Tracing methods execution time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, trace, .net-trace

I am trying to "inject" custom tracing methods in my application.

I want to make it as elegant as possible, without modifying to much of the existing code, and have the possibility to enable / disable it easily.

One solution i could think of would be to create a custom `Attribute` which i will attach it to the methods i want to trace.

Basic idea:

```
public class MethodSnifferAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Stopwatch sw = null;

    public void BeforeExecution()
    {
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
    }
    public void ExecutionEnd()
    {
        sw.Stop();
        LoggerManager.Logger.Log("Execution time: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [MethodSniffer]
    public void Function()
    {
        // do a long task
    }
}
```

Are there any existing `.NET` attributes that provides callbacks for when a method is called / ended?

Comment: I don't think I know about any.

Comment: What you're looking for is in the area of aspect oriented programming. There's a library called [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) which does exactly what you want. If you're looking for open source solutions, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net) post.

Comment: Postsharp will make this very easy for you. You can even apply your aspects on an entire namespace through AssemblyInfo.cs. Check it out at: https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: ASP.NET has support for filters: `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`. Of interest: `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`.

Comment: PostSharp is free or licensed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attribute's method are not called unless you call it manually. There are security attributes which are invoked by the CLR but that's beyond the subject of this question and it will not be useful anyway.

There are techniques to rewrite your code at different level. Source code weaving, IL weaving etc.

You need to look at some way to modify the IL and rewrite it for timing the execution. Don't worry, you don't have to write all of that. People have already done it. For example, you can use [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).

Here's an [article](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/aop-method-execution-time-watcher-with-postsharp/) which provides an example

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class LogExecutionTimeAttribute : OnMethodInvocationAspect
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogExecutionTimeAttribute));

    // If no threshold is provided, then just log the execution time as debug
    public LogExecutionTimeAttribute() : this (int.MaxValue, true)
    {
    }
    // If a threshold is provided, then just flag warnning when threshold's exceeded
    public LogExecutionTimeAttribute(int threshold) : this (threshold, false)
    {
    }
    // Greediest constructor
    public LogExecutionTimeAttribute(int threshold, bool logDebug)
    {
        Threshold = threshold;
        LogDebug = logDebug;
    }

    public int Threshold { get; set; }
    public bool LogDebug { get; set; }

    // Record time spent executing the method
    public override void OnInvocation(MethodInvocationEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        eventArgs.Proceed();
        sw.Stop();
        var timeSpent = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (LogDebug)
        {
            Log.DebugFormat(
                "Method [{0}{1}] took [{2}] milliseconds to execute",
                eventArgs.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
                eventArgs.Method.Name,
                timeSpent);
        }

        if (timeSpent > Threshold)
        {
            Log.WarnFormat(
                "Method [{0}{1}] was expected to finish within [{2}] milliseconds, but took [{3}] instead!",
                eventArgs.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
                eventArgs.Method.Name,
                Threshold,
                timeSpent);
       }
}
```

Note: I've modified the example from the article to use `StopWatch` instead of `DateTime` because `DateTime` isn't accurate.

Comment: Well done for using `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime`

Comment: Since `OnMethodInvactionAspect` is not longer supported, you can use `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`, for an example of how to use this for tracking execution time of a method see the [docs](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator#sharing-state-between-advices)

Answer (score 1):

You can trace method execution time easily with PostSharp (available as NuGet package). Code of custom method-level attribute that doing just that (taken from [here](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/aop-method-execution-time-watcher-with-postsharp/)):

```
  [Serializable]
  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public sealed class LogExecutionTimeAttribute : OnMethodInvocationAspect
  {
  private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogExecutionTimeAttribute));

  // If no threshold is provided, then just log the execution time as debug
  public LogExecutionTimeAttribute() : this (int.MaxValue, true)
  {
  }
  // If a threshold is provided, then just flag warnning when threshold's exceeded
  public LogExecutionTimeAttribute(int threshold) : this (threshold, false)
  {
  }
  // Greediest constructor
  public LogExecutionTimeAttribute(int threshold, bool logDebug)
  {
    Threshold = threshold;
    LogDebug = logDebug;
  }

  public int Threshold { get; set; }
  public bool LogDebug { get; set; }

  // Record time spent executing the method
  public override void OnInvocation(MethodInvocationEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    eventArgs.Proceed();
    var timeSpent = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;

    if (LogDebug)
    {
    Log.DebugFormat(
    "Method [{0}{1}] took [{2}] milliseconds to execute",
    eventArgs.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
    eventArgs.Method.Name,
    timeSpent);
    }

    if (timeSpent > Threshold)
    {
    Log.WarnFormat(
    "Method [{0}{1}] was expected to finish within [{2}] milliseconds, but took [{3}] instead!",
    eventArgs.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
    eventArgs.Method.Name,
    Threshold,
    timeSpent);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this work in .net Core and can you give a usage example please? - is it literally just adding this to the top of a method:  [LogExecutionTimeAttribute]