# How to get a method called (decorator?) after every object method

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, decorator, python-decorators

This is a question similar to [How to call a method implicitly after every method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075283/how-to-call-a-method-implicitly-after-every-method-call) but for python

Say I have a crawler class with some attributes (e.g. self.db) with a `crawl_1(self, *args, **kwargs)` and another one `save_to_db(self, *args, **kwargs)` which saves the crawling results to a database (`self.db)`.

I want somehow to have `save_to_db` run after every `crawl_1, crawl_2, etc.` call. I've tried making this as a "global" util decorator but I don't like the result since it involves passing around `self` as an argument.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `crawl_1` throws an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to implicitly run a method after all of your `crawl_*` methods, the simplest solution may be to set up a metaclass that will programatically wrap the methods for you.  Start with this, a simple wrapper function:

```
import functools

def wrapit(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def _(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.save_to_db()

    return _
```

That's a basic decorator that wraps `func`, calling
`self.save_to_db()` after calling `func`.  Now, we set up a metaclass
that will programatically apply this to specific methods:

```
class Wrapper (type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, nmspc):
        for attrname, attrval in nmspc.items():
            if callable(attrval) and attrname.startswith('crawl_'):
                nmspc[attrname] = wrapit(attrval)

        return super(Wrapper, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, nmspc)
```

This will iterate over the methods in the wrapped class, looking for
method names that start with `crawl_` and wrapping them with our
decorator function.

Finally, the wrapped class itself, which declares `Wrapper` as a
metaclass:

```
class Wrapped (object):
    __metaclass__ = Wrapper

    def crawl_1(self):
        print 'this is crawl 1'

    def crawl_2(self):
        print 'this is crawl 2'

    def this_is_not_wrapped(self):
        print 'this is not wrapped'

    def save_to_db(self):
        print 'saving to database'
```

Given the above, we get the following behavior:

```
>>> W = Wrapped()
>>> W.crawl_1()
this is crawl 1
saving to database
>>> W.crawl_2()
this is crawl 2
saving to database
>>> W.this_is_not_wrapped()
this is not wrapped
>>>
```

You can see the our `save_to_database` method is being called after
each of `crawl_1` and `crawl_2` (but not after `this_is_not_wrapped`).

The above works in Python 2.  In Python 3, replase this:

```
class Wrapped (object):
    __metaclass__ = Wrapper
```

With:

```
class Wrapped (object, metaclass=Wrapper):
```

Comment: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html is useful reading on metaclasses.

Comment: [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is a convenient way to set `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes.

Comment: Good suggestion; I updated the answer to use `functools.wraps`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'Calling decorated function'
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = args[0] if len(args) > 0 else None
        if obj and hasattr(obj, "bar"):
            obj.bar()

    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    @my_decorator
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Calling foo"

    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Calling bar"

@my_decorator
def example():
    print 'Called example function'

example()

obj = MyClass()
obj.foo()
```

It will give you the following output:

```
Calling decorated function
Called example function
Calling decorated function
Calling foo
Calling bar
```

Comment: `obj = args[0] if len(args) > 0 else None` should be `obj = args[0] if args else None`: an empty `tuple` is "falsey", non-empty "truthy" when evaluated in a boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator in Python looks like this, it's a method taking a single method as argument and returning another wrapper method that shall be called instead of the decorated one. Usually the wrapper "wraps" the decorated method, i.e. calls it before/after performing some other actions.

Example:

```
# define a decorator method:
def save_db_decorator(fn):

    # The wrapper method which will get called instead of the decorated method:
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fn(self, *args, **kwargs)           # call the decorated method
        MyTest.save_to_db(self, *args, **kwargs)   # call the additional method

    return wrapper  # return the wrapper method
```

Now learn how to use it:

```
class MyTest:

    # The additional method called by the decorator:

    def save_to_db(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Saver")


    # The decorated methods:

    @save_db_decorator
    def crawl_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Crawler 1")

    @save_db_decorator
    def crawl_2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Crawler 2")


# Calling the decorated methods:

my_test = MyTest()
print("Starting Crawler 1")
my_test.crawl_1()
print("Starting Crawler 1")
my_test.crawl_2()
```

This would output the following:

```
Starting Crawler 1
Crawler 1
Saver
Starting Crawler 1
Crawler 2
Saver
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Q6tvpA)