# Why .NET Garbage collector donot invokes destructor of an abandoned object?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have a simple Account class. When I create an object referenced by "a". But after that I assign null to a. Further I have invoked GC.Collect(), whose job is to clear all abandoned object from heap memory.
And since the object earlier referenced by a is not more referenced by any reference variable so it should be cleared and hence it's destructor should have been invoked. But surprisingly I am not getting the desired output.

1. Is CLR performing some optimization ?

```
class Account
{
    int AccountNo;
    string Name;
    decimal Balance;
    public Account()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("account object created");
    }
    ~Account()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("account object destroyed");
    }
}

class ObjectOrientedExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        a = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a destructor in C#. There's a *finalizer*, and its syntax matches C++'s destructor syntax, but it's not a destructor.

Comment: Furthermore, *"A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run at any point prior to program termination."* See: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

Comment: Then what is the use of GC.Collect(), it is used to forcefully clear the unreferenced objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to force C# finalizers be run in .NET Core on program exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66863320/is-it-possible-to-force-c-sharp-finalizers-be-run-in-net-core-on-program-exit)

Comment: Where is object referenced by a is? In G0?

Comment: Running finalizers at program exit was a feature of AppDomain, it was lost in .NETCore.  You now have to provide enough time to give them a chance to run yourself, add `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`.  Target at least .net6.0

Comment: You, probably, are looking for `IDisposable` interface and `Dispose` method which is *guaranteed* to be executed when `a` is out of scope `using Account a = new Account();`

Answer (score 1):

C# uses a **finalizer**, which is different from a destructor. Finalizers are **not deterministic**. You can't know for sure when they will run, even if the GC collects an instance of the object.

Mostly in C# you don't write finalizers at all. In fact, it's *really rare*. Instead, if you need deterministic disposal of a resource (other than memory!), you should implement the `IDisposable` pattern for the object. Adding a finalizer might be *one part* of this pattern, but it doesn't have to be, and in fact should *only* be done if you are managing a brand new kind of resources that doesn't already provide a finalizer somewhere in the inheritance tree.

Comment: What does "collect them" means ? Does it mean that GC has recognised that this object is abandoned and ready for garbage collection ? Or the objects memory is released and made free ?