# Avoid repeating parts in methods

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with avoiding repeating parts in methods. I have class with multiple methods. I have some kind of validation method that should be invoked in the begining of each method or before each method is invoked. For exmple:

```
public class TestClass
{
     public Test(){}
     private void Validate(){ // some code }

public IList<User> GetUsers()
{
  Validate();
//other content
}

public IList<Product> GetProducts()
{
  Validate();
//other content
}


public IList<Role> GetRoles()
{
  Validate();
//other content
}

public Product CreateProduct()
{
  Validate();
//other content
}

}
```

Is there better approach for doing that instead of invoking Validate() in each method?

Comment: These methods are not in controller

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC and it's just a c# question. Look up aspect-oriented programming which aims to solve exactly this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method implicitly after every method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075283/how-to-call-a-method-implicitly-after-every-method-call)

Comment: I don't understand why getter methods require validation since the data in the instance _shouldn't change_ and we can assume it has already been validated.