# Custom attribute on return value with ability to access method input parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, aop, custom-attributes

I'm trying to take an advantage of AOP with custom attributes and I want to implement a custom attribute which affects return method value based on input parameters. There is a way to define an attribute for a return value:

```
[return: CustomAttribute]
public string Do(string param1)
{
    // do something
}
```

but I couldn't find a way how add a desired behavior when this attributes is applied. I want to execute some code, based on value of input parameters and in certain cases even change the output value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not provide any AOP related syntax. `[return: CustomAttribute]` adds metadata information to return type. That's not what you expect at all. In order to leverage AOP you need to either:

- Use an external library designed specifically to allow AOP. Here's a [nice list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net) of such libraries.
- If you're using container then it may support AOP. For instance here's [a link](http://structuremap.github.io/interception-and-decorators/) to StructureMap AOP related documentation.
- You may try to implement AOP features on your own, but it's pretty hard (especially if you care about performance).

Comment: I was ready to get this answer... my research already told me that .net and c# are not ready for AOP

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. :) .NET and C# are just fine with AOP. There is no syntax designed explicitly to use aspects, but there are plenty of libraries which gives such capabilities. I've edited my answer to include [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do something ugly, which gets your result, but it's well... ugly.

```
public class UglySolution
{
    private static string _changedString;

    private class CustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CustomAttribute()
        {
            _changedString = "New";
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass()
        {
            _changedString = "Original";
        }

        [Custom]
        public string GetValue()
        {
            typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("GetValue").GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<CustomAttribute>().First();
            return _changedString;
        }
    }
}
```