# Dependencies between (injected) services

Tags: dependency-injection, language-agnostic

I'm building a web application and have a service layer for business logic. These services are injected into the controllers. Now, I'm wondering what the best practice is in the following situation.

---

I have a `AuthenticatorService` that, unsurprisingly, is responsible for authentication. When a user attempts authenticating, this is clearly something that should be logged. That's something a `LoggerService` can handle.

Right now, I'm injecting a `LoggerService` into the `AuthenticatorService`, but having dependencies between services does not feel very clean...

I'm binding concrete types to interfaces, so logically speaking I would say this is fine - obviously given that it is absolutely certain that the injected service will never have a reason to rely on the other, thus creating a circular dependency.

I'm very interested in reading how others are solving this problem - or, whether it is not a problem at all.

Please do not suggest handling logging from the controller - this is just an example, and there's a lot more situations imaginable where one service might want to call another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm very interested in reading how others are solving this problem - or, whether it is not a problem at all.

Yes, it is a problem - in fact, it is one of the most asked about problems. The name of this problem is [crosscutting concerns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx). There are several different ways that the problem could be tackled.

1. Framework-specific - in MVC/WebApi, there are [filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) that can run logic in specific controllers, actions, or on every request.
2. Using a 3rd party [Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net).
3. Using common design patterns such as [proxy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy) or [decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator). Here is an [proxy example using the .NET RealProxy class](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp-with-realproxy/).
4. [Interception](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/09/25/interception-vis-a-vis-pure-di/), a feature built into several major dependency injection frameworks.