# Dependency injection ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I read this article: http://peterspattern.com/dependency-injection-and-class-inheritance/ (great article btw)

Now, I have an ASP.NET Core web application, and I am thinking about putting all my services inside another class and use the built in DI to resolve this. Only reason I want to do this is to not have to manually update every constructor each time there is a need to add a new service to some class.

For example, instead of:

```
public class Foo {
IServiceOne _serviceOne;
IServiceTwo _serviceTwo;

 public Foo(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo) {
   _serviceOne = serviceOne;
   _serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
 }
}
```

I can do this:

```
public interface IMyServices {
  IServiceOne ServiceOne {get;}
  IServiceTwo ServiceTwo {get;}
 }

public class Foo {
   IServiceOne _serviceOne;
   IServiceTwo _serviceTwo;

    public Foo(IMyService services) {
      _serviceOne = services.ServiceOne;
      _serviceTwo = services.ServiceTwo; 
    }
}
```

*Edit: (I have left some parts out, like the class that implements IMyService and the registration of the service in Startup.cs)*

Now, the application I am working on is quite large and the class that would be containing all the services could possibly contain 20-30 services.

My question is: is this a good idea? My concerns are with performance. Passing in all services in all constructors even if they are not needed feels like a bad idea. But it would save us tons of time if there would be only one class to update with a new service, then that service is available in all classes.

Is there perhaps someway to lazy load services when they are actually requested, or is that done by default?

Comment: If your classes contain too many dependencies, that's a good sign the class isn't following the single responsibility principle and is trying to do too much.

Comment: Sounds to me as if you might want to first figure out whether your class actually needs 20-30 services or if you could split that up in the first place. Some other things to consider would be whether the injections should be transient, per request or singletons -- that will probably have an effect as well. I've worked on a website which had some parts where it used a single aggregation dependency object and that turned out to be a cause of slowness due to the excessive unnecessary resolving. Though you should probably measure those things to see if it's an actual issue in your case.

Comment: Suggest you read up on SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and SoC (Separation of Concerns). This has a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that article you linked to combined a real-world problem with a solution to a *different* problem ([constructor over-injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorover-injectionanti-pattern/)). It didn't address the original problem, which was [using inheritance for a Controller in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119206/what-are-good-candidates-for-base-controller-class-in-asp-net-mvc).

It is *really smelly* to have to inject the same service into all of your controllers. This puts the problem squarely in the context of [crosscutting concerns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx).

As I pointed out earlier [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193234), there are several ways to tackle this issue, the best of which in .NET Core are [*filters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) and [*middleware*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

I suppose inheritance is also an option, but it is *clearly the worst one*, as it will inevitably lead to creating a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

> **NOTE:** I am not saying that inheritance is not valuable in certain situations, but Controllers are generally not one of those situations.

Comment: Funny thing is that [the author](http://peterspattern.com/dependency-injection-and-class-inheritance/) completely misinterpretted the [Aggregate Service pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). His solution is _not_ an implementation of an Aggregate Service.